# In which episode of the F/SN Unlimited Blade Works anime do we see Illya's body Command Seals?

Tags: fate-stay-night

I'm looking for a scene like this? What episode, and extra credit for timings as well. Thanks.

[image: Illya with command seals all over the place]

Comment: Are you referring to the visual novel (which this image probably comes from), or the recent anime adaptation?

Comment: @Maroon sorry I mean the anime adaptation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The picture you have provided has the art style of a game/visual novel and not that of an anime, especially the background.

This is because the scene is not shown in the anime adaptation of Fate/Stay Night: Unlimited Blade Works, or any of the other anime adaptations of the Fate series, but is from the [Visual Novel's First Route: **Fate**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQJyW.jpg).

Here is a picture of her Magic Circuits without the background along with some information about it:

> [image]
>
> Illya has unsurpassed potential as a Master amongst all Masters past and present. 70% of her body is composed of Magic Circuits. They are also her Command Spell and show themselves as a red pattern all over her body when she generates magical energy.<sup>[Source](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Illyasviel_von_Einzbern)</sup>

Comment: Yes I know this is not shown in the anime. I'm asking for any scenes showing her command seals. The provided picture was just an example.

Comment: I used that very sprite myself to create the example image.

Comment: @Harry What do you mean by her command seals, if not the red markings on her body? As for the episode number, the episode of F/SN UBW that may have what you're looking for is Episode 15. Although, I scrolled through the episode and didn't find anything, but I can guarantee that Episode 15 is the only one that may have the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks I see some face-marks in 15. Are the seals shown in the bathing scene after berserker / archer/saber fight?

Comment: @Harry Sorry, I forgot to reply. I don't think they are.